# ffmpeg leak detection

Tags: c#, ffmpeg

I'm currently doing some conversion work with ffmpeg building with gcc under mSys for the DLLs and some plain C wrapper code which I'm then calling from C#.

If I use the MS crtdbg.h I'm not now showing any memory leaks (I did have a couple) BUT I'd like to check if I've left behind a leak within the ffmpeg code which I assume is using a gcc libc library.

For example I was using some AVDictionary objects which I'd forgotten to clearup afterwards, I'm worried there may be some more elsewhere that I've missed.

Anyone got any advice on how to confirm that I'm not leaking memory in the ffmpeg DLLs?

Comment: The pragmatic way: write a test program that does whatever you need to do over and over again as fast as possible.  Let it run over the weekend.  If it still runs Monday morning then you don't have a serious leak.

Comment: Thats my fall back position but I hate doing it that way.